# MS Access and Excel instantiation, xlup not defined

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So I am using late binding, i.e. `set objxl = createobject("Excel.Application")` type stuff, switching over from early binding where it was `set objxl = new excel.application` or whatever, but now pieces like `.end(xlUp).row` throw errors because `xlUp` isn't defined.

Comment: use `-4126` instead `xlUp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because xlUp is defined in Excel, not in Access. You can replace xlUp with the corresponding numerical value (not a great idea imho) or you can define the constants in Access.

```
Private Const xlUp as long = -4162
```

This is a bit more work, but allows you to use xlUp, making your code more readable and likely more maintainable down the road as well.

Comment: Is there a master list of all these constants being declared/defined? I can't seem to find one and I have a LOT of "xl" codes that would be tedious to replace with hardcodes

Comment: Also I noticed when I try declaring it like that, I get an error, but if I hardcode it, it works

Comment: I've always just used defined what I've needed by looking at the definition of a constant in VBA within Excel, but a quick google search came up with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197824(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Ah, found out why. It's -4162, not -4126 (answer is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be more efficient to set the reference to Excel (VBA screen, Tools, References, select Microsoft Excel (Ver #) Object Library? Then one can code as if using Excel. Just be careful - once the Access module has run, it may leave EXCEL.EXE running.